# T-SQL Compare 2 Usernames

Tags: t-sql

I have 3 tables below. I am trying to compare the roles of each user. That is I want to show that John has 2 roles while Jane has 1. Currently I am only showing the common roles between them.

- `Sec_role (PK R_KEY, rname)`
- `Role_User(PK R_KEY, PK USER_KEY)`
- `User(PK USER_KEY, Name)`

Sample data:

```
Sec_Role          Role_User       User

R_Key|rname|      R_Key|User_Key  User_KEY|NAME
1    |Analyst     1    |1         1       |John
2    |Sysadmin    2    |1         2       |Jane  
                  2    |2
```

I am trying to get

```
User | Role    | User2 | Role2  
John | Analyst | Jane  | (Empty because she isn't an analyst)   
John | sysadmin| Jane  |Sysadmin
```

---

```
SELECT U.Name AS User1,  
       U2.Name AS User2,  
       R.rname AS Role1  
       R2.Rname AS Role2  
FROM Sec_Role AS R
LEFT OUTER JOIN Role_User AS RU
ON R.R_Key=RU.R_Key
LEFT OUTER JOIN User AS U
ON U.User_Key=RU.User_Key

LEFT OUTER JOIN Sec_Role AS R2
ON R2.R_Key=R.R_Key  <---(I think this is the issue here)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Role_User AS RU2
ON R2.R_Key=RU2.R_Key
LEFT OUTER JOIN User AS U2
ON U2.User_Key=RU2.User_Key

WHERE U.Name ='John'
AND U2.Name='Jane'
```

Currently I am getting the Intersection of these two Users.

```
User | Role    | User2 | Role2   
John | sysadmin| Jane  |Sysadmin
```

Comment: Help with _what_? You didn't explain what you _are_ getting.

Comment: I am getting the intersection of these users. just what's common between them.

Comment: maybe post the example data in each table...  difficult to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE U.Name ='John'
OR U2.Name='Jane'
```

note an OR not an AND

why the 4 columns

```
    SELECT U.Name AS User,  
           R.rname AS Role   
    FROM Sec_Role AS R
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Role_User AS RU
    ON R.R_Key=RU.R_Key
    LEFT OUTER JOIN User AS U
    ON U.User_Key=RU.User_Key
    where uName in ('','')
    order by 1, 2
```

Try this

```
 SELECT U.Name AS User1,  
   U2.Name AS User2,  
   R.rname AS Role1  
   R2.Rname AS Role2  
 FROM Sec_Role AS R
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Role_User AS RU
 ON R.R_Key=RU.R_Key
 LEFT OUTER JOIN User AS U
   ON U.User_Key=RU.User_Key
   and U.Name ='John'

 LEFT OUTER JOIN Sec_Role AS R2
 ON R2.R_Key=R.R_Key  <---(I think this is the issue here)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Role_User AS RU2
 ON R2.R_Key=RU2.R_Key
 LEFT OUTER JOIN User AS U2
   ON U2.User_Key=RU2.User_Key
   AND U2.Name='Jane'
```

Comment: It's a requirement to show the User Names next to each other rather than underneath.

Comment: No, it compared every user in the entire user table

Comment: While it didn't work for me, I found a solution based on using the username in the LEFT JOIN as you did above. Thank you